# What is the proper way to handle SQLITE database in XCode5?

Tags: database, xcode, sqlite, connection, xcode5

I'm new to XCode and Objective C programming. I'm developing an iPhone app related to events, and for this purpose I will be using SQLITE as my database. To try out how things work, I created and inserted a record into database and that seems to be working fine. However, my question is: **Should I assign db-path (database path), db(database) and SQL on every controller that accesses database or should I make a master controller to handle connection**.

Note: I come from PHP coding background.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question did not make sense to much of the viewers. The thing i wanted to ask was: what is the best practice of handling database in Objective C with Xcode? Should I create a master database object that creates, accesses and updates the table and then import that same object wherever needed? Or do I make a connection and write sql each time? What is the best way to do it (especially with SQLITE).